# how to import multiple table data using single query running to page

Tags: laravel

I have Two tables same column,

table one - Books
ID | Title | Description

table Two - Novels
ID | Title | Description

So I want to export these table data to My "NewReleases.blade.php"

Can you any one help me to do this, Normal query or Ajax

Currently I'm Using this Query to Execute data

```
$Post = Books::where([['status','Published']])->paginate(32);
        return view('View.ViewBookssAdds',['adds' => $adds])
```

;

Answer (score 0):

The `merge` function maybe will help you to merge your two queries to a single one;

```
$Novel = Bovels::where([['status','Published']]);
$Post = Books::where([['status','Published']])->merge($Novel);
```

Also, you can try `union` function if it didn't work.

Comment: @sameera maybe you should test it without the pagination.